# Prove Identity Function is Isomophic

Tags: group-isomorphism

From Dr. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra":

> Let $G$ be any group. If $\epsilon: G \rightarrow G$ is the identity function, $\epsilon(x)=x$, show that $\epsilon$ is an isomorphism.

Here's my attempt:

**Claim**: $\epsilon$ is injective.

**Proof**: since $\epsilon$ is the identity function, then each element of $B$, i.e. the *range*, is the image of no more than one element of $A$, i.e. the *domain*.

**Claim**: $\epsilon$ is surjective

**Proof**: since $\epsilon$ is the identity function, then each element of $B$, i.e. the *range*, will equal its input, i.e. $x$ from $\epsilon(x)$. As a result, each element of the *range* of at least one element of the *domain*.

**Claim**: $\epsilon(ab)=\epsilon(a)\cdot\epsilon(b)$.

**Proof**: I'm *assuming* that I can choose multiplication as the operation between $a$ and $b$. As a result, the commutativity of multiplication results completes the proof.

Did I prove that $\epsilon$ is isomorphic?

Comment: $\epsilon\left(ab\right)=ab=\epsilon\left(a\right)\epsilon\left(b\right)$. Commutativity plays no part. The statement is true for any group. Also groups that are not abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't exactly "choose" what operation $G$ has. It's part of the pack "$G$ is a group", which is actually the short form for "$G$ is a group with operation $\bot$, and we write $\bot(a,b)$ as $ab$". I've used a generic symbol but it could have been any other, this depends on the context.

Anyways, the correct way of concluding is to actually take the *image* of $ab$ under $\epsilon$ (as we probably would, were $\epsilon$ any other map): $$\epsilon(ab) = ab$$

Now how can you rewrite both $a$ and $b$? The answer is that, since $\epsilon$ is the identity, $a=\epsilon(a)$ and $b = \epsilon(b)$. Therefore the last expression is equal to (by transitivity of the equals sign) $\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$.

Comment: I see. So the operation in this exercise is $\epsilon$, i.e. the identity function. drhab's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/75923/drhab) demonstrates that $\epsilon(ab)=ab=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$?

Comment: @KevinMeredith No! The operation is most certainly not $\epsilon$. The operation is unnamed here, so we denote it (as you have) by simply placing letters next to each other (when the letters represent group elements).

Comment: I don't understand the unnamed operation part. Can you please answer your question (that you posed to me): "Now how can you rewrite both $a$ and $b$"?

Comment: @KevinMeredith By unnamed operation I only mean that we don't have a symbol such as $+$,$\cdot$,$\times$,$\oplus$,$\bot$,$\dots$ that we write between two elements $a$,$b$ to denote the operation done on them, because all that is said is "let $G$ be any group". By convention though, we write $ab$ for the result of the group operation on the pair $(a,b)$. Sometimes this ambiguity is avoided by saying "Let $(G,[\text{some symbol}])$" be a group, and this means that the group operation will be written as $a\,[\text{some symbol}]\,b$. (...)

Comment: (...) This only affects how we write things though, see edit for your other question.

Comment: So, $\epsilon(ab)=ab$ since $\epsilon$ is the identity function? As a result, $a$ and $b$ can be replaced with $\epsilon(a)$ and $\epsilon(b)$, respectively? Finally, that results in $\epsilon(ab)=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$, **QED**?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes, the definition of the identity function is that $\epsilon (g) = g$ for any $g\in G$.

Comment: @KevinMeredith What you are saying in your last comment on this question is exactly what I meant to say by stating: $\epsilon(ab)=ab=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$. First equation $\epsilon(ab)=ab$ and secondly equation $ab=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are replaced by $\epsilon(a)$ and $\epsilon(b)$ respectively.